# IDA Pro Hexrays Decompiler MEMORY[0x40080] Error

Tags: c++, c, decompiling, ida

I'm using IDA Pro 7.0 with Hexrays plugin to decompile some C++ code.

I very often encounter some functions that their de-compiled code just looks wrong and display them in red foreground color like so:

```
MEMORY[0x1008] = 1;
if (MEMORY[0x1008])
....
```

And very often I get at the top of my function the following red statement:
// write access to const memory has been detected, the output may be wrong!

My assumption that it's somewhat related to stack issues.

How can I fix the this the de-compiled code would just look cleaner?

TIA for any help and pointers!

Comment: Did you rebased your code in IDA? Rebased code might show that kind of behavior.

Comment: @Train, not really. Just loaded it as is into ida.